# Mercurial обновление версии

Tags: контроль-версий, mercurial

Есть репозиторий, созданный на старой версии Mercurial. Репозиторий используется локально, т.е. нет ситуации, когда возможны подключения клиентов разных версий. Теперь обновили Mercurial до версии 4.9.

Надо ли как то делать обновление самого репозитория, чтобы была возможность пользоваться функциями новой версии?

Answer (score 0):

> Надо ли как то делать обновление самого репозитория?

Нет. Такого действия нет вообще.